# getting attr from select 2 option on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Im using Select2 to create filters for my Wordpress archives with the help of Ajax requests.

Im using code like this to create my Select2 lists:

```
<select id="land_vehicle_categories" class="select2" multiple="multiple">
 <?php
    $land_vehicle_categories = get_terms('vehicle_categories', 'parent=145' );
    foreach ($land_vehicle_categories as $land_vehicle_category) {
        echo '<option title="' . $land_vehicle_category->slug . '">' . $land_vehicle_category->name . '</option>';
    }
 ?>
</select>
```

However, the output is way different because of the way Select2 works, meaning I can no longer make use of the `title` to get the `attr` when clicked.
I need to store the `title` in a var when the option is clicked and I cannot find a way to do this because of the way Select 2 converts the code.

Can anybody help me out with this?
Thanks!!

Comment: why don't you use `value` which is typically required for `<option>`?

Comment: Can use value attribute?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion guys. I managed to achieve the filtering in a completely other way, so problem solved! (-: